# How to get user's id (user_id) of each member using a checkbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I was trying to send an email to multiple user using checkbox but the problem is only the last member on the list will get the email and not everyone. Please help me guys.
This is the code for the checkbox with the members including the button for sending:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb{{$i}}" value="{{$member->user_id}}">
    <label class="col-md-5 boxed" for="cb{{$i}}">
        {{$member->email}}
    </label>
```

This is for the submit button:

```
<a data-gid="{{$event_group->eg_id}}"
   data-userid="{{$member->user_id}}"
   data-user-name="{{$member->first_name}}">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Friends</a>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$(".invitation").click(function (event) {
        var user_id = $(this).attr("data-userid");
        var user_fullname = $(this).attr("data-user-name");
        var r = confirm("Send Email Invitation?");
        if (r){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{Extras::getEUserURLPath( Auth::user()->user_id, '/ajax/sendFriendsInvitation')}}",
                data: {
                    user_id: user_id,
                    event_group_id: $("#eg_id").val(),
                    _token : ""
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.response);
                    if(data.response == true){
                        alert("Email Invitation Sent!");
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                }
            });
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
$(function(){

$("#click").on("click",function(){
 var users=[];
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.is(":checked")){
        users.push($this.attr("id"));
    }
});
console.log(users);//pass this array to your send mail part
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1:<input type="checkbox" id="id_1">
2:<input type="checkbox" id="id_2">
3:<input type="checkbox" id="id_3">
4:<input type="checkbox" id="id_4">
5:<input type="checkbox" id="id_5">
<button id="click" >Click</button>
```

The Other way using array map() is little faster.

```js
$(function(){

$("#click").on("click",function(){
 var users=[];
 users=$("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('id');

        }).get();
console.log(users);//pass this array to your send mail part
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_1">
<input type="checkbox" id="id_2">
<input type="checkbox" id="id_3">
<input type="checkbox" id="id_4">
<input type="checkbox" id="id_5">
<button id="click" >Click</button>
```

Comment: This can be optimized.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry but I'm having an error using your code

Comment: it says `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` but I don't see any missing **;** on your code

Comment: @Newbie see the code in demo...use console to see output.

Comment: @Suchit can you do it by editing newbie's code? I don't think he/she gets it. Neither do I

Comment: @JaneDoe it's embarrassing but yes I don't. I tried using the code it does not work

Comment: @Suchit thank you so much for your effort but I don't know how to use them right.

Comment: @JaneDoe what is it you are not getting. he can send the users array instead of user_id to the backend where he will process this array to send mails to each user in array users.

Comment: @Newbie in your ajax use `user_id: users,` instead of `user_id: user_id,` then loop it in your mail functionality part to send to each user.

Comment: @Newbie or use you ajax in loop but it will make as many calls as selected users.Which is not a good idea.

Comment: @Suchit I removed this line `$("#click").on("click",function(){` before adding the other lines of your code and it working but after clicking send it now shows `Error: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/C.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/C.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/C.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/C.overrideMimeType(),etc`

Comment: I think the problem now is in the controller where I will send multiple emails. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var id = $('[type=checkbox]:checked').attr("id");
```

This is a generic way of writing. If you have multiple check boxes it will cause issue. I suggest that the selector should me more specific.

If you are selecting multiple then use this

```
var id = $('[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();
```

You will get `id` as an array.

Comment: It's not working . The `data-userid` can be found on the submit button

Comment: So you want the id of the checkbox checked when you click submit button?

Comment: It's now working, Sir. Thank you but it only works on a single id

Comment: Ok fine then. Happy coding `:)`

Comment: Wait. Can you help me on how to make it send to multiple email address?

Comment: Sorry but I kind of having an error using the multiple email

Comment: Since it is an array you have to change your code as well. You have to loop through it.

Comment: Oh okay. I don't really know how but I think I'm using up your time. Thank you very much